# What's wrong in my useEventListener.js that generates me useEventListener error all the time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

what's wrong with my useEventListener ? Because each time I click on checkboxes I get this error :

```
useEventListener.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: callbackRef.current is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.internalCallback (useEventListener.js:14:1)
```

useEventListener.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
export default function useEventListener(eventType, callback) {
    const callbackRef = useRef(callback)

    useEffect(() => {
        callbackRef.current = callback
    })    
    useEffect(() => {    
        function internalCallback(e) {
            return callbackRef.current(e)
        }    
        document.addEventListener(eventType, internalCallback);
        return () => document.removeEventListener(eventType, internalCallback)
    }, [eventType])
}
```

I use my hook here:

```
export default function useQuery(query) {
    const [queryList, setQueryList] = useState(null)
    const [isMatch, setIsMatch] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const list = window.matchMedia(query)
        setQueryList(list)
        setIsMatch(list.matches)
    }, [query])    
    useEventListener('change', ((e) => setIsMatch(e.matches), queryList))    
    return isMatch
}
```

Comment: where do you use your hook? do you always pass `callback` as a function?

Comment: Hi, I've update the issue with additional code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue is in what you are passing to the custom hook:

```
useEventListener('change', ((e) => setIsMatch(e.matches), queryList))
```

The code here is passing a Comma Operator expression.

[Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left
> to right) and returns the value of the last operand. This lets you
> create a compound expression in which multiple expressions are
> evaluated, with the compound expression's final value being the value
> of the rightmost of its member expressions. This is commonly used to
> provide multiple parameters to a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

In other words, the expression is evaluated and the result of the final operand is returned, `queryList` in this case.

It's not clear what the intent was in includeing `queryList`, but you should remove the comma operator expression and pass just the callback function to the custom hook.

Example:

```
useEventListener('change', (e) => setIsMatch(e.matches));
```

Comment: Hi, I've added new [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657845/react-why-does-only-my-first-set-of-selected-rows-turn-into-gray-before-moving-a) related to one of my previous issue and the answer that you gave me, [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669743/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-with-toggle-button), [issue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672391/react-display-data-depending-on-the-value-of-a-variable-apply-and-send-apply). If you have time to look at them please :)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you pass `((e) => setIsMatch(e.matches), queryList)` as a second argument to `useEventListener`. [Here's what MDS says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So your `useEventListener('change', ((e) => setIsMatch(e.matches), queryList))` is equivalent to `useEventListener('change', queryList)`. Since `queryList` is not a function, you get the `callbackRef.current is not a function` error.

**UPD**

I would also remove the callback ref in the `useEventListener` hook. It makes sense to remove an old listener and attach a new one when the callback changes. It works in the same way but is way easier to read:

```js
export default function useEventListener(eventType, callback) { 
    useEffect(() => {    
        function internalCallback(e) {
            return callback(e);
        }    

        document.addEventListener(eventType, internalCallback);

        return () => document.removeEventListener(eventType, internalCallback);
    }, [eventType, callback]);
}
```