# REACT- My condition is working partially why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my json file from my api, I have a variable `apply`, If `apply:0`, Then It should should print my data and If `apply:1`, Then It should hide my data (i.e row in my Table). Actually when I combine my 2 conditions, It is partially working :`(applyStatus ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1)) && (showGood ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good"))`, i.e Only the `...showGood ?...` condition is working and the `...applyStatus?...` not working.

Whereas if I do only :

`<Table data={matchData && (applyStatus ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1))>` . Then, I have my data where `apply:0`  are displayed.

What's wrong in my code please ?

```
export default function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState({});
  const [menus, setMenus]=useState([])
  const [showGood, setShowGood] = useState(false);
  const [applyStatus, setApplyStatus] = useState(false);

  if (menus.apply === 0) {
    setApplyStatus(true)
}
if (menus.apply === 1) {
  setApplyStatus(false)
}

  useEffect (() => {
    axios.post("",{menuId:parseInt(menuId)})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setMenus(res.data.menus)
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}, [menuId]);

useEffect (() => {
  const GoodMenus = menus.filter((i) => i.taste === "Good");
  const restOfMenus = menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good");      
  setMenus([...GoodMenus, ...restOfMenus]);
}, [menus]);


  // If any row is selected, the button should be in the Apply state
  // else it should be in the Cancel state
  const buttonMode = Object.values(selected).some((isSelected) => isSelected)
    ? "apply"
    : "cancel";

  const rowSelectHandler = (id) => (checked) => {
    setSelected((selected) => ({
      ...selected,
      [id]: checked
    }));
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (buttonMode === "apply") {
      // Hide currently selected items
      const currentlySelected = {};
      Object.entries(selected).forEach(([id, isSelected]) => {
        if (isSelected) {
          currentlySelected[id] = isSelected;
        }
      });
      setHidden({ ...hidden, ...currentlySelected });

      // Clear all selection
      const newSelected = {};
      Object.keys(selected).forEach((id) => {
        newSelected[id] = false;
      });
      setSelected(newSelected);
    } else {
      // Select all currently hidden items
      const currentlyHidden = {};
      Object.entries(hidden).forEach(([id, isHidden]) => {
        if (isHidden) {
          currentlyHidden[id] = isHidden;
        }
      });
      setSelected({ ...selected, ...currentlyHidden });

      // Clear all hidden items
      const newHidden = {};
      Object.keys(hidden).forEach((id) => {
        newHidden[id] = false;
      });
      setHidden(newHidden);
    }
  };

  const matchData = (
    menus.filter(({ _id }) => {
    return !hidden[_id];
  });

  const getRowProps = (row) => {
    return {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: selected[row.values.id] ? "lightgrey" : "white"
      }
    };
  };

  const data = [
    {
      Header: "id",
      accessor: (row) => row._id
    },
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: (row) => (
        <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row._id}` }}>{row.name}</Link>
      )
    },
    {
      Header: "Description",
      //check current row is in hidden rows or not
      accessor: (row) => row.description
    },
    {
      Header: "Dishes",
      //check current row is in hidden rows or not
      accessor: (row) => row.dishes,
      id: "dishes",
      Cell: ({ value }) => value && Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
    },
    {
      Header: "Status",
      accessor: (row) => row.status
    },
    {
      Header: "Show",
      accessor: (row) => (
        <Toggle
          value={selected[row._id]}
          onChange={rowSelectHandler(row._id)}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  const initialState = {
    sortBy: [
      { desc: false, id: "id" },
      { desc: false, id: "description" }
    ],
    hiddenColumns: ["dishes", "id"]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        {buttonMode === "cancel" ? "Cancel" : "Apply"}
      </button>
      show good
      <Toggle value = {showGood} onChange={() => setShowGood(!showGood)} />
      <Table
        data={matchData &&(applyStatus ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1)) &&
        (showGood ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good"))}
        initialState={initialState}
        withCellBorder
        withRowBorder
        withSorting
        withPagination
        rowProps={getRowProps}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here my json from my api for `menuId:1`:

```
[
  {
    "menuId": 1,
    "_id": "123ml66",
    "name": "Pea Soup",
    "description": "Creamy pea soup topped with melted cheese and sourdough croutons.",
    "dishes": [
      {
        "meat": "N/A",
        "vegetables": "pea"
      }
    ],
    "taste": "Good",
    "comments": "3/4",
    "price": "Low",
    "availability": 0,
    "trust": 1,
    "status": "Pending",
    "apply": 1
  },
  //...other data   

]
```

Comment: really hard to understand what you ar easking, but if you need to post something, create a function that does this and then handle the response just like you do on initial load. You can also filter the res.data.menus using .map and use useeffect to trigger a re-render, but that would not be posting new data.

Comment: @Rmaxx, I've edited the question cuz as you said it's hard to understand so I've divided my question into 2 this one and the sending part  where I've made a post function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686224/react-post-data-not-working-when-i-submit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually in the usage of your parenthesis. Your current logic looks like this.

```
(applyStatus ? 
    menus : 
    menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1)
) && (showGood ? 
    menus : 
    menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good")
)
```

If you simplify it it looks like

```
(Condition ? array : filteredArray) && (Condition ? array : filteredArray)
```

If you simplify it again it results in

```
array && array
```

When you are using `&&` operator on two array like you are doing it will return you the second array which in your case is the array filter on `i.taste !== "Good"`.

I tried to show it with a code sample below

```js
const array = [{price:5, age:10},{price:3, age:8},{price:9, age:12},{price:12, age:13}];

const ageFiltered = array.filter(x => x.age < 11);
const priceFiltered = array.filter(x => x.price > 4);

console.log("Age filtered:" + JSON.stringify(ageFiltered));
console.log("Price filtered:" + JSON.stringify(priceFiltered));

const result = ageFiltered && priceFiltered;
console.log("&& operator:" + JSON.stringify(result));

const doubleFiltered = array.filter(x => x.age < 11 && x.price > 4);
console.log("Dobule filters:" + JSON.stringify(doubleFiltered));
```

To fix your issue your code must be update to be like this

```
menus.filter(i => (applyStatus ? true : i.apply !== 1) && (showGood ? true : i.taste !== "Good") )
```

Comment: by adding your solution to my code, it works partially because now I'm not able to hide the selected rows (when you click on the button under the Show column. And when I do : `<Table data ={matchData}.../>` it works fine but then if I add : `<Table data={menus.filter(i => (applyStatus ? true : i.apply !== 1) && (showGood ? true : i.taste !== "Good") )}.../>` . Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grayline-issue-with-condition-uk63zw) before the addition of the 2 conditions. Do you see what could be wrong please ?

Comment: I've opened my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804638/why-does-my-condition-disable-one-of-my-feature-using-react)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because [&&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) only return the value of the last operand. So i think your code should be this

```
            <Table
                data={
                    matchData && menus.filter(i => {
                        if (applyStatus) return true;
                        return i.apply !== 1;
                    }).filter(i => {
                        if (showGood) return true;
                        return i.taste !== 'Good'
                    })
                }
                initialState={initialState}
                withCellBorder
                withRowBorder
                withSorting
                withPagination
                rowProps={getRowProps}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  if (menus.apply === 0) {
    setApplyStatus(true)
}
if (menus.apply === 1) {
  setApplyStatus(false)
}
```

from my understanding `menus` is an array so there is nothing like `menus.apply` so its either you loop the menus checking if apply is true. then there is no need for
`===0`  just check if its true(1) or false(0).

if you want to display those that has apply you can sort them by using map just after fetching them like this

```js
useEffect (() => {
    axios.post("",{menuId:parseInt(menuId)})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            let data_ =res.data.menus
            let_apply_true = []
            let apply_false = []
       data_.map((data)=>{
if(data.apply){
let_apply_true.push(data)

}
//else will return those that are false
 let apply_false.push(data)
})



            setApplyMenus(let_apply_true)   //
            setNotApplyMenus(let apply_false)
            setMenus(res.data.menus)
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}, [menuId]);


//that is just one way 
//
```